# Call third party application from Wp8 app

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have tried to Launch Hotmail App from my app but could not do so.
Is there anyway to call/list third party application in my WP8 app?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What's the "hotmail" app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [LaunchUriAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh701480.aspx) to launch the email app (I assume this is what you mean by Hotmail app), using a `mailto:` format URI. See [MSDN for reference and a list of other URI/files types you can use for other built-in apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662937%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

You can't list 3rd party apps, only other applications you yourself have published in the Store.